# Configurable Procucts appear as out of stock in frontend

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, frontend, out-of-stock

I´m facing some problem in make my configurable products appear in frontend, no matter what i do (i´d read an tried other posts solutions) it appears as out of stock in my frontedn.

Follow configs so you can see if you can help me out:

At the main configurable product -> stock

Manage stock = yes
Allow product increment = yes
Availability = in stock

Product category -> egypt

Than i´d created a buch of simple products from my configurable one as quickly associated product:

status = enabled
visibility = not visible individualy
amount = 1000
availability = in stock

Problems:
1) when I save the associate product it does not save my product category (egypt) , it stays without any category.

2) Even if I manualy go in each product and set the category to Egypt (a looot of work) in my frontend it still appear as out of stock.

Just to let you know, if I go to my configurable product at backend -> associate products, it shows the simple products created as associated normaly.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: new info: I´ve just created a simple product by duplicating another simple product, I´d changed it´s category and althought in my backend it is ok it doesnt appear in my front end in neither category (nor in the new or the old category)

Comment: Hey guys, any clue on what is the matter here?